# UMLのアクティビティ図はフローチャートの代わりとして使えますか？

Tags: uml

少し気になったことがあったんで質問します。
私も当初はフローチャートを使っていたのですが、
UML図を書く「[Visual Paradigm（日本語版もあるらしいのですが音沙汰なしなので英語版です）](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/)」の無料版を導入してから、フローチャートに相当するアクティビティ図を使おうと考えています。
しかし、不安な点も少しあり、いちばん有名なクラス図の資料はたくさんあるのですが、
UML2のアクティビティ図の日本語の情報が必要最低限のものなのがネックです。
そのため、英語の情報を参考にアクティビティ図を書いているのが現状です。
そこで質問なのですが、アクティビティ図はフローチャート図の代わりとして使えるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

一般的にアクティビティ図は基本的にビジネスロジックの処理の流れを表現し
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/dd409465.aspx

フローチャートはソフトウェアのアルゴリズムが表現されることが多いです。
https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%95%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88

規格によってはフローチャートは並行処理が記述できなかったりするのですが、
とくに制約がないのであれば、ドキュメントで「何を表現したい」か「表現したいことが表現できるか」というベースで考えればいいと思います。

フローチャートを拡大解釈したものがアクティビティ図という解釈をしておりおそらくフローチャートで表現できていたものであればアクティビティ図で表現することは可能かと思います。

あえて懸念を上げるならばアクティビティ図はいろいろ表現できるのででソフトウェアのアルゴリズムのようなシンプルなモノを表現するには気をつけないと、現実とはかけ離れたものになりがちな点ですかね。